# Drawing a simple triangular prism in opengl in 3D

Tags: opengl, c++, 3d, glut

Is there a simple way to draw a triangular prism in opengl?

I'm using lighting and a non-orthographic camera. I basically need a 3d object, not just vertices.

*edit:* well I've tried searching, and I tried doing it with two cubes. One that is rotated at an angle from the other, but logically that doesn't work. I have to get an object with angles less than 90 degrees.

[image]

I basically need something like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just provide the vertices yourself:

```
// bottom
0, 1, -1/2
√3 / 2, -1/2, -1/2
-√3 / 2, -1/2, -1/2

//Top
0, 1, 1/2
√3 / 2, -1/2, 1/2
-√3 / 2, -1/2, 1/2
```

Then the indices:

```
// Bottom
0, 1, 2,

// Top
3, 4, 5,

// Side1
0, 1, 3,
3, 1, 4,

// Side 2
1, 2, 4,
4, 2, 5,

// Side 3
2, 0, 5,
5, 0, 3,
```

Comment: so I just have to use `glVertex3f()` for all the vertices to draw it? Is there no other way? Some kind of an object like the cube?

Comment: @MinaMichael First, you shouldn't use OpenGL 1, it's deprecated and some GPUs don't support it anymore. Anyways, you need to call them based on the indices, how do you draw a cube?

Answer (score 0):

So Bálint's advice works. Here's how to do it in code. You can define a function that draws a triangular prism at the centre using glVertex3f() functions

```
void triangularPrism()
{
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0, 0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5, 0, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0, -0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5, 0, 0.5);

        glVertex3f(0.5,0,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5,1,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,1,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,0,-0.5);

        glVertex3f(0.5,1,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,1,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,0,0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0,0.5);
    glEnd();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0,0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5,1,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(0.5,0,-0.5);

        glVertex3f(-0.5,0,0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,1,-0.5);
        glVertex3f(-0.5,0,-0.5);
    glEnd();
}
```

Then this function can be used in the glutDisplayFunc() just like the other primitives. You can translate it, scale it, rotate it and so forth. Example:

```
glPushMatrix();
    glTranslated(1.5,1.1,2.75);
    glRotated(180,0,1,0);
    glRotated(flapsDegree, -1,0,0);
    glScaled(0.5,0.8,0.1);
    triangularPrism();
glPopMatrix();
```